# Android Google Map V2 getting Blank screen with zoom in & zoom out but no map

Tags: android, google-maps

I followed the instruction given in the net by you in https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435, I made the app & try to run it by my Galaxy S IV, but getting blank screen with + and - button, for your convince I am also giving all the files of the project to you. Please help me.

1.AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapwithgps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<permission android:name="com.example.mapwithgps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapwithgps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapwithgps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCNChGhmjHFvLp4atblSojMLvnnfg-_QZA" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

2.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

3.MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mapwithgps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Please help me to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

**it seems like you have problem with api key !**

**try**  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html  **tutorial with all steps!**

Answer (score -1):

I see you have stumbled on my Google Maps Guide. Well fist of all if you `minSDKVersion` is 14, there is no point in using the `FragmentActivity` and `SupportMapFragment` objects, you can just change them to a simple `Activity` and a `MapFragment`.

Second if you followed all the steps of this guide and you still have a problem of a blank map with zoom controls I would suggest you to go over this guide as well:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

and make sure that you produced the key and configured it correctly in the Google API Console.